# Existence of a local spinor bundle

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, spin-geometry

I am confused about the existence of a local spinor bundle.

My question is that if a Riemannian manifold $M$ is not spin, why does there exist a local spinor bundle over all sufficiently small open subsets of $M$?

Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If "As we all know, it is easy to construct a spinor bundle on a Riemannian spin manifold," why is this in doubt for a _local_ question...? This isn't a dismissive comment; just not sure what is the point of uncertainty. Locally the frame bundle of a Riemannian manifold is trivial. If that isn't apparent, or if the sufficiency of this fact isn't apparent in constructing a local spinor bundle, then this question is really asking something other than it appears.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang l edited my question again. Could give me some help? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would help to remind us all what a spin structure actually is.

Comment: The answer in my comment is, locally the frame bundle (with structure group $SO(n)$) is trivial, so a double-covering homomorphism $\operatorname{Spin}(n) \to SO(n)$ induces a mapping $U \times \operatorname{Spin}(n) \to U \times SO(n)$ of (total spaces of) principal bundles in a trivializing neighborhood $U$. But is that the question being asked...?